# How to access a value from an NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have a NSMutableArray in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method:

```
[self.somethingSelected addObject:[self.arrayFromTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

The output of this self.somethingSelected (an NSMutableArray) is the following. How do I access just the id value from the following output?

I want self.somethingSelected to store "11,9,21..." and none of the other values like title, etc...

```
(
    {
        id = 11;
        title = Title0;
    },
    {
        id = 9;
        title = Title1;
    },
    {
        id = 21;
        title = Title2;
    },
)
```

I tried:

```
[self.somethingSelected addObject:[self.arrayFromTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"id"];
```

but I think I'm mixing up NSDictionary and NSMutableArray, perhaps.

Comment: The last code snippet seems fine. What error are you encountering exactly?

Comment: what happened when you used ? `[self.somethingSelected addObject:[self.arrayFromTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"id"];`

Comment: I was missing the [] as per @David Ben Ari post below.

Comment: In iOS >=5 tableViews support multiple selection if this is what you are trying to roll your own version off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if arrayFromTable holds NSDictionaries than what you tried should work, but you are missing a '[' & ']'. it should be:

```
    [self.somethingSelected addObject:[[self.arrayFromTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"id"]];
```